# Getting the coordinates of points along a poly-line shown in graphics

Tags: graphics, coordinate

I have been trying to obtain list of {x,y} coordinates from this code

```
Graphics[
  Line[
    Table[
      {r*Cos[θ*Degree] + x, r*Sin[θ*Degree] + y}, 
      {θ, 0, 360, 360/4}] /. {r -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1}]]
```

Its output is

[image]

I want the output to be a list of all `{x, y}` coordinates like what Mathematica sees. For example,

[image]

I could perhaps control the point density. Could this be possible?

Comment: `Graphics[...][[1, 1]]`?

Comment: @Kuba no.basically i wanted to avoid writing equations of these polygon lines  and somehow get the coordinates.I hope i am a bit more clear.

Comment: `InputForm[%] gives you what Mathematica sees.  It doesn't see as many points as you do.

Comment: Do you want the problem solved for all `Graphics[]` or just the problem given above? (I doubt it can be done for ***all*** graphics or rather that someone would do it.  What would you want for a `Rectangle[]`, the two corners specified or all four corners? Etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g0 = Graphics[Line[Table[{r*Cos[θ*Degree] + x, r*Sin[θ*Degree] + y}, 
  {θ, 0, 360, 360/4}] /.  {r -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1}]];
```

We can also construct a [`BSplineFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineFunction.html) from extracted line coordinates

```
 bSF = BSplineFunction[g0[[1, 1]], SplineDegree -> 1];
```

and map it on an equally spaced list of desired length:

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Small], Point[bSF /@ Subdivide[100]]}, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
Row[Graphics[{PointSize[Small], Point[BSF /@ Subdivide[#]]}, 
    ImageSize -> 2 (# /. 4 | 8 -> 20)] & /@ {4, 8, 40, 100, 300}, Spacer[20]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is very good.Thankyou

Answer (score 8):

You can interpolate between the corners to get coordinates along the lines. `n` controls the number of points for each line.

```
square = Graphics[Line[Table[{r*Cos[\[Theta]*Degree] + x, r*Sin[\[Theta]*Degree] + y}, 
    {\[Theta], 0, 360, 360/4}] /. {r -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1}]];

n=10
points = Flatten[Table[t*#1 + (1 - t) #2, {t, 0, 1, 1/n}] & @@@ 
    Partition[square[[1, 1]], 2, 1], {1, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{1., 2.}, {1.1, 1.9}, {1.2, 1.8}, {1.3, 1.7}, {1.4, 1.6}, {1.5, 1.5}, 
>  {1.6, 1.4}, {1.7, 1.3}, {1.8, 1.2}, {1.9, 1.1}, {2., 1.}, {0., 1.}, 
>  {0.1, 1.1}, {0.2, 1.2}, {0.3, 1.3}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.5, 1.5}, {0.6, 1.6}, 
>  {0.7, 1.7}, {0.8, 1.8}, {0.9, 1.9}, {1., 2.}, {1.,0.}, {0.9, 0.1}, 
>  {0.8, 0.2}, {0.7, 0.3}, {0.6, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.5}, {0.4, 0.6}, {0.3, 0.7},
>  {0.2, 0.8}, {0.1, 0.9}, {0., 1.}, {2., 1.}, {1.9, 0.9}, {1.8, 0.8}, 
>  {1.7, 0.7}, {1.6, 0.6}, {1.5, 0.5}, {1.4, 0.4}, {1.3, 0.3}, {1.2, 0.2},
>  {1.1, 0.1}, {1., 0.}}
> ```

```
ListPlot[points, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Using `Cases`, you can extract the information you need from any graphics. From the following graphics:

```
gr = Graphics[
      Line[
        Table[{r*Cos[θ*Degree] + x, r*Sin[θ*Degree] + y}, {θ, 0, 360, 360/4}] 
         /. {r -> 1, x -> 1, y -> 1}
      ]
     ];
```

We want to extract the `Line`s: this can easily be done by

```
Cases[gr, Line[__]]

(* Out: {Line[{{2, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}]} *)
```